# Electrum open source mobile wallet

Tags: wallet, electrum

I am looking for open source mobile wallet which supports electrum protocol.

Already found 2:

1. https://github.com/coreyphillips/moonshine
2. https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair-mobile

But first one looks buggy and unfinished.
Eclair-mobile is too bound to its back-end Eclair core part, which is written in Scala. Sorry but for me its overkill.

Can community recommend any other OSS Electrum mobile wallets?

Comment: Electrum runs on mobile too :P

Comment: when I say Electrum I  mean ServerSide API Electrum https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html

Comment: Yeah, and Electrum connects using that protocol. Why are you using the word wallet, if you are not looking for wallets?

Comment: There many wallets which are same as Electrum(you mentioned) supports Electrumx/Electrum on server side. Moonshine is one of them. I wanna find out others.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Electrum branded [mobile wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.electrum.electrum) with [source code](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/gui/kivy/Readme.md):

It's OS with a MIT license.